# Fastest way to find which data type in a file

Tags: hadoop, bigdata

My question is very simple but it can be in fact a real headake.
What is the more effecient and fastest way to determine which kind of data is inside a file.

If you have for example a raw file with undred of columns ...

Do you have tips to provide me ? :)

ps: i am using python for small files and hortonworks for big ones.

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

In fact i would like a fast return like this:
`truckid STRING,
driverid STRING,
event STRING,
latitude DOUBLE,
longitude DOUBLE,
city STRING,
state STRING,
velocity INT,
event_ind INT,
idling_ind INT`